# Mapstruct upgrade when using Lombok `@With` annotation

Tags: lombok, mapstruct

While upgrading from 1.2.0 version to 1.4.2 I've encountered several obstacles that seems the upgrade is not backwards compatible.

One issue I've had was that with this version the source cannot be a setter method. The property must exist.
Another issue I've had was with Lombok's `@With` annotation that now seems to make Mapstruct ask for a lot of mapping rules for each `with...` where ... are property names in the entire class. How can these be turned off ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is a problem with the Lombok `@With`. You can follow [this](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1740) issue.

In the meantime you can write your own custom `AccessorNamingStrategy` that will ignore those methods.